# Sending a file stream in JSON

Tags: javascript, angular, file, blob

Can I send the stream of data from a File or Blob and post it in JSON in Angular 5?
I tried using a FileReader, but not able to get the stream out of it using the 
 result property.

```
  let blobfile=new Blob([this.curResume]);
  let fr=new FileReader;
  fr.readAsText(blobfile);
  console.log(fr,fr.result);
```

This is how I've tried it and this is what I get in the console.
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Duq8y.png)

Comment: Changes made in question

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you are trying to push a file to the server using POST API call. In that case you can pass it as formData.

Please be a little eloborate on adding your question.

```
const fileData= new Blob([this.yourFile], { type: "<your File type>" });
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("yourFile", fileData);

this.httpClient.post(<your url>, formData);
```

Comment: Import statements would be very helpful, especially regarding Blob and FormData.

Comment: Nothing to import explicitly for FormData and Blob as they are Web APIS.

Comment: Can you help how a c# API works with the FormData or should I ask another question? I am not familiar with c#.. Just to show something to our service man

Comment: I am not familier with c#.